# Increase mouse pointer speed

Tags: windows-vista, mouse, dpi

I have a [Microsoft Basic Optical mouse](http://www.compusa.com/applications/SearchTools/item-details.asp?EdpNo=784879&CatId=539) on a Windows Vista 32-bit machine, with IntelliPoint 8.0 installed.  In the Mouse properties in Control Panel, I have my pointer speed set to the maximum setting for how fast it can go, with the "Enhance pointer precision" option checked.

My issue is that the mouse moves too slowly.  I have dual monitors (one 24", one 20"), and I have to pick up and set down the mouse several times to get the pointer from one monitor to the other.  I realize that the "Enhance pointer precision" option, when unchecked, increases the speed of the mouse, but it does so at the cost of decreased precision, and makes the mouse infuriatingly imprecise, which I'm not willing to deal with.

What options do I have to increase the mouse pointer's speed?  Should I downgrade IntelliPoint to a version that had the acceleration options?  Is there an option somewhere in the registry that can increase the DPI of the mouse?  Is there another piece of software that can increase the mouse pointer speed?

**More Info:**
I stumbled upon a command line utility called [MouseSpeed](http://nd.snackbox.org/pages/apps/mousespeed.html) that looked promising, but alas, Windows won't allow you to increase the mouse's speed past its maximum value of 20, which corresponds to the maximum value in the slider in the mouse properties in the Control Panel.

Comment: lubricate your desk?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a to buy a mouse with a higher DPI in order to have speed and accuracy. I have a very similar setup: 24" monitor and 22" monitor I had to upgrade my mouse because I could not find a good balance of speed and accuracy with my old one. I went with a laser mouse they have excellent accuracy. [This](http://www.tigerdirect.com/applications/SearchTools/item-details.asp?EdpNo=5214793&CatId=2390) is the mouse I bought, I know it's a little pricey but trust me the extra money was worth functionality I got from it.

Comment: Thanks, Kyle.  It looks like you get what you pay for with cheap mice.  Incidentally, I've got a similar mouse at home to the one you linked to, and it's fantastic.