# How to replicate pointer acceleration of Logitech SetPoint software in my Microsoft mouse?

Tags: dpi, logitech-mouse, mouse-acceleration

Pictures are worth a 1000 words, so let me jump right to it:

[image: Screen shot of Logitech SetPoint]

In Logitech's SetPoint software, I could change the pointer acceleration. I love this feature because it allows me to keep the DPI lower, which is good for precision tasks, but at the same time I can still send the pointer all over the screen with little wrist movement. Best of both worlds!

I just recently got a used MS Sidewinder X8 mouse. Neither the more basic IntelliPoint software which comes with the driver nor the optional, more fancy, Microsoft Mouse and Keyboard Center have this feature! This is pretty aggravating... I thought it was a standard feature found in every mouse software. (Is it not?? Is Logitech special for having it?) How can I make my MS X8 mouse behave in the same way as my Logitech mice? I've been relying on this pointer acceleration feature for years now.

Is there perhaps any 3rd party solution? I looked into [X-Mouse Button Control](http://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/XMouseButtonControl.htm), but it doesn't seem like that program has that (according to [this](http://forums.highrez.co.uk/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=551&p=2431&hilit=acceleration#p2431) thread). Also, user Tim S. Van Haren mentioned in this Super User [thread](https://superuser.com/questions/211410/increase-mouse-pointer-speed) that earlier versions of IntelliPoint did have acceleration setting(s). Does anyone know more about that? Maybe that's my only option?? If so, which version do I need?

**

PS: Kind of meta, but maybe creating a "microsoft-mouse" tag would be appropriate here since there is one for "logitech-mouse".

Answer (score 4):

Mouse acceleration is controlled by the `Enhance pointer precision` option in the mouse settings dialogue. The actual acceleration is controlled by a series of inflexion points along a curve, which are set using the `SmoothMouseXCurve` and `SmoothMouseYCurve` settings in the registry. You could try modifying these settings to get the mouse response that you're looking for.

There's a wealth of detailed knowledge in [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/278362/windows-mouse-acceleration-curve-smoothmousexcurve-and-smoothmouseycurve), and [this link](http://www.esreality.com/index.php?a=post&id=1945096) - too much, I feel, to list here. There are equations and tools on the second link to help you calculate your own acceleration curve.

Apologies if this seems like a 'post a link' answer.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this answer? If it solved your problem, could you please mark it as answered?

Comment: Unfortunately I ended up running out of time to spend on this. Back in school now and no time for anything other than school. Eventually I'll probably look into this again. Winter break or something.